# Laravel 5 catching PayPal PHP API 400 errors on localhost:8000

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Using the PayPal API with my Laravel 5.2 install, specifically this package: https://github.com/anouarabdsslm/laravel-paypalpayment

The package works great! and I am taking payments perfectly! I am struggling to catch and redirect when incorrect details e.g. bank card details are entered by a user. The Laravel application just throws a 400 error.

What I am wanting to do is catch the errors and redirect back and notify the user.

The code below is where I make a request:

```
try {
    // ### Create Payment
    // Create a payment by posting to the APIService
    // using a valid ApiContext
    // The return object contains the status;

    $payment->create($this->_apiContext);

} catch (\PPConnectionException $ex) {
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors([$ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL]);
}

dd($payment);
```

When a successful payment is made I get a nice return object that I can reference and action accordingly, when there is an issue like a 400 error it kills the application completely and DOES NOT catch and redirect the errors back to the user.

The error code messages are:

```
PayPalConnectionException in PayPalHttpConnection.php
Got Http response code 400 when accessing 
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.
```

Has anyone faced similar issues with the PayPal PHP API?

I know when the application isn't in dev mode I can have error pages specifically to catch certain error codes. But I really want to catch errors and redirect back to the form with notifications for the user.

Thanks in advance to any wizard who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right guys,

I posted the answer here: [Laravel 5 catching 400 response from PayPal API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258214/laravel-5-catching-400-response-from-paypal-api) but I want to make sure anyone hitting this thread knows how I solved the issue!

It would appear that Laravel's default `Exception` method was interfering with the PayPal API `PayPalConnectionException`. So I modified the code to catch general `Exception` errors only as it contained all required error objects. The `\` before `Exception` was critical! as it needs the correct namespace (in my case anyway, your application may be different).

```
try {
    // ### Create Payment
    // Create a payment by posting to the APIService
    // using a valid ApiContext
    // The return object contains the status;
    $payment->create($this->_apiContext);

} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors([$ex->getData()])->withInput(Input::all());
}
```

This [link](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/exception-'PayPal%5CException%5CPayPalConnectionException'-with-message-'Got-Http-response-code-400-when-accessing) that @rchatburn posted was highly useful, the application always seemed to catch at the point `\Exception` and NOT `\PayPalConnectionException` once I had everything namespaced correctly.

In my investigations I came across `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`. Here you can extend the render method to grab a `PayPalConnectionException` and handle the errors uniquely to that specific exception . See code:

```
//Be sure to include the exception you want at the top of the file
use PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException;//pull in paypal error exception to work with

public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    //check the specific exception
    if ($e instanceof PayPalConnectionException) {
        //return with errors and with at the form data
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($e->getData())->withInput(Input::all());
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Either work great, but for me it felt neater to just change the catch method to a lookout for a general `Exception`, where I am testing if a payment was successful.

Hope this helps anyone facing similar issues :D!!!

Nick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want The JSON details of your API call you can ADD the following code.

```
  try {
          // ### Create Payment
          // Create a payment by posting to the APIService
          // using a valid ApiContext
          // The return object contains the status;
          $payment->create($this->_apiContext);
      } catch (\Exception $ex) {
          return dd($ex->getData());
          exit(1);
      }
```

Hope it helps you